# Android screen auto rotate disabled after requesting location updates

Tags: android, location, screen-orientation, autorotate

When I request location updates in my Android activity, the automatic screen rotation stops working across all apps in the device. It does not work even after I kill the app, lock device & unlock, switch auto-rotate off & on in settings. In fact I don't know what exactly I need to do to let it work again. It just starts working by itself after some time.

I discovered that when I remove command `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` screen rotates fine, when I use that command, screen stops auto-rotating.

Can anybody explain me what am I doing wrong? BTW, I am running my app on Nexus 9 with Android Nougat (7.1.1)

```
GoogleApiClient m_GoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest m_LocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*.....*/

    m_GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

    m_LocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    m_LocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    m_LocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    m_LocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            // WHEN I REMOVE FOLLOWING LINE, AUTO-ROTATE WORKS
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(m_GoogleApiClient, m_LocationRequest, this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // NO EXPECTION CAUGTH
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    /*....*/ // THE CODE HERE DOES NOT INFLUENCE THE SCREEN ROTATION ISSE
}
```

Overall the code for getting location updates works fine, it's just the screen that stops auto-rotating...

Comment: I tried linking to play-services:9.0.0 and play-services:10.0.1, made no difference

Comment: My code is exactly same as in [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Comment: Can you test your code on a different device and a different Android version? Looks like a bug to me.